# rails redirect_to analog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a service using Rails 3. The service mainly provides some API-methods, but there are also some special web-pages for end-users with friendly interface - these web-pages are basically a "cover" for API.

So what I need to do is to make a little coding in `CoverController` and then redirect to API method (different controller). This method needs to be called via `POST` as it contains some sensible info (e.g. access-tokens) that an end-user should not see.

As I understand HTTP standard it is not possible to redirect via `POST`, but the method I need to call is just another function in neighboring class! Is there a way to call it with everything (`params`, etc.) properly set *as if* it was called from browser? Or should I just use `Net::HTTP::Post` and call myself?

Answer (score 0):

you can call the method:
    # in controller

```
# action 1
def action1
  ...
  action2
end

# must be called via post
def action2
  ...
end
```

this of course, assuming action2 can use the existing params list passed to action 1. Otherwise, you can also fill it up.

Comment: This is great but seems to work like GET - can see all parameters in the URL in the browser.
In my case `action2` is from another controller so I call it like
 `ApiController.action2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking the wrong way. Rails 3 is so nice that you can call actions and the results are based on the way you call the action.

Small example: a api to return the current time:

```
def gettime
  @time = new Date
  # and do all other important stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json:  @time }
    format.html { render 'gettime' } # renders gettime.html.erb
  end
end
```

if called as an api, it returns a json object. If called from browser, it returns a html page. This way you won't duplicate code, and obide the rule that actions are user initiated, or redirected to after another action.

Also other developers will understand your code, and it will be placed exactly at the location where it belongs.

BTW: there is no such thing as 'hiding' sensible parameters by using post. Any browser shows this info with one shortcut.

Comment: Your example is Ok while you have one-to-one correspondence between user actions and code. Let's say we have one API method that needs to be called from three actions differently; or one action that needs to call two API methods in a row.

I can move the code to Model, but it is not exactly what I want and not much flexible.

By hiding parameters I mean that calling API method from server-side, I can set sensible parameters and end-users won't see them (because they are set on server), unless they become a part of URL and can be seen in rendered view.